# Mongodb get detailed index info

Tags: mongodb, indexing, info

Can somebody tell me please if is possible to get detailed info about indexes in Mongodb? I need to show the time when index was created. But command:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').getIndexes()
```

does not show this information. Is there any way do it? Thanks.

Comment: MongoDB does not store such information as a "creation date" of the index. The most detailed information you can get is from `db.getCollection('collectionName').stats({ indexDetails: true }).indexDetails` to just narrow down the "index parts" of the full collection stats. Nothing in there about creation date. You can use `db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate({ "$indexStats": {} })` to return things like "access statistics" on collection indexes, but again this does not return a "creation date".

Comment: Also, this does not really seem like a "programming" question unless you are creating a tool for administering MongoDB data. Database administration questions should be asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: If I want to find command it is programming question.